# Can't do intent on MapFragment class to another activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I've already searched and tried many ways on doing Intent like getActivity() / v.this / and my app still stop working when clicking this TextView to get to reserveReply class which only do simple ImageView.

---- MapFragment.class ------

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
```

// I put the intent on the front of the codes just to test btw

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MapFragment.this, reserveReply.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    final String parkname = (String) v.getTag();
    final String name = "Testing Test";
    final String age = "21";



    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("firstname",parkname);
            parameters.put("lastname",name);
            parameters.put("age",age);

            return parameters;


        }

    };

    requestQueue.add(request);

}
```

}

---- reserveReply.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation_reply);

    imgReply  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgReply);
    imgReply.setImageResource(R.drawable.waiting);

}
```

}

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReserveReply.class);` is not working? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: yes. it's not working. I'll edit and put my codes.

Comment: Put also sourcecode of reserveReply.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried to implement View.onClickListener in fragment but it is not working. instead use setOnClickListener method directly and do your stuff... upvote if you like it...

Comment: Thanks ! this worked for me. I dont know why android has this kinds of problems it's irritating sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FragmentView extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { 

TextView newsTitle; 

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

newsTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
newsTitle.setOnClickListener(this);

return rootView;    
}

public void onClick(View view) {

       switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.news_title:
                // code
                break;
        }
     }
}
```